# Using TP4056 with two unprotected batteries

Tags: switches, tp4056

For a small hobby project that I am doing, I need to power a simple RF receiver and other components with 5 V DC.

The first attempt I made was with one LiPo cell, a boost converter and a TP4056 charging module.
The problem was that the converter was too noisy for the RF module. Furthermore the rest of the circuit required a peak current of 700 mA which the converter cannot handle.

So I switched to two LiPos in series and a buck converter. I had no more noise problems but, in order to charge and protect the batteries I have to use two TP4056 modules with all the intricacies that this solution implies. I am using the same approach depicted [here](https://www.instructables.com/2S-LiPoLion-Battery-Charger-Using-Micro-USB-5V2A-P/). The only difference is that I prefer to use a 4PDT slide switch instead of the hack he made.

I then discovered that such switches aren't rated for the amount of current that I require during the charging phase (about 2 A). A switch similar to [this one](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-cell-lipo-charging?view=all#overview) should do the job. By the way they are able to use a simpler 3PDT switch, probably because they are using different chargers, I think.

These big switches are too big for my little project. I wonder if it is possible to solve the problem in a different and not too complex way. Maybe a solid state relay or some IC that I don't know can do the job. Avoiding the switch altogether and sensing the connection to the main USB charger would be even better!

Comment: Your RF receiver requires 700 mA?????

Comment: @Andyaka No :-) the receiver requires only 4 mA, but there is also a 4 W speaker in the circuit.

Comment: A 2-cell charger and a proper 2-cell BMS might be a better solution than a complex switching arrangement on top of the wrong tools for the job.